# Uploading multiple images on different fields

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm using the code that appears on https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload to upload an image to the server. But this code only returns multiple images on the same field.
How can I upload multiple images in different fields?

```
const addUploadCapabilities = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === 'UPDATE' && resource === 'posts') {
        if (params.data.pictures && params.data.pictures.length) {
            // only freshly dropped pictures are instance of File
            const formerPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => !(p instanceof File));
            const newPictures = params.data.pictures.filter(p => p instanceof File);

            return Promise.all(newPictures.map(convertFileToBase64))
                .then(base64Pictures => base64Pictures.map(picture64 => ({
                    src: picture64,
                    title: `${params.data.title}`,
                })))
                .then(transformedNewPictures => requestHandler(type, resource, {
                    ...params,
                    data: {
                        ...params.data,
                        pictures: [...transformedNewPictures, ...formerPictures],
                    },
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any update on this problem ?